# How can I show a messagebox or loadingbox while doing a loop? (Code may be blocked and after 25 seconds continue)

Tags: c#, timer, sleep, box

I already have this but it doesn't work... I need to check if a bit from plc is high or not. If it is still high I need to wait 5 seconds and check again.. Now I am trying to find something so there is some visual feedback for the user. In a textbox I want to put 'waiting...' while the points after waiting increase per 5 seconds. I tried a lot of things but can't seem to get it to work. Mostly of the time's it just hangs 25 seconds without updating the GUI and then it continues... :/

```
// First check if the plc bit, that says if there is still an order active, 
// is still set. If so then we wait a couple seconds.
var bitorder = Main.PIOGetValue(jbmis.IO_GET_INPUT, "BoxManInStarted");
int counter = 1;
string loadingpoints = "";

loadtimer.Tick += timer_Tick;
loadtimer.Interval = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds;
loadtimer.Start();
loadtimer.Enabled = true;

// Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

while(bitorder != 0 && loadtimercounter != 25)
{
    // TODO multithreaded

    #region testcode
    // MessageBox.Show("Waiting for previous order to be stopped" + loadingpoints);
    // Context.UserMessageService
    //     .ShowMessage("Waiting for previous order to be stopped" + 
    //                  loadingpoints, "Waitingfororder");
    // sw.Start();

    // while (sw.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(25)) 
    // {
    //     if (sw.Elapsed.Seconds % 5 == 0)
    //     {
    //         loadingpoints = loadingpoints + ".";
    //         tbScannedEANPick.Background = Brushes.OrangeRed;
    //         tbScannedEANPick.Text = "Waiting" + loadingpoints;
    //     }                                        
    // }

    // sw.Stop();
    // loadingpoints = loadingpoints + ".";
    // tbScannedEANPick.Background = Brushes.OrangeRed;
    // tbScannedEANPick.Text = "Waiting" + loadingpoints;
    // tbScannedEANPick.UpdateLayout();
    #endregion

    if (loadtimercounter % 5 == 0)
    {
        loadingpoints = loadingpoints + ".";
        tbScannedEANPick.Background = Brushes.OrangeRed;
        tbScannedEANPick.Text = "Waiting" + loadingpoints;
        tbScannedEANPick.IsReadOnly = true;

        bitorder = Main.PIOGetValue(jbmis.IO_GET_INPUT, "BoxManInStarted");
    }

    counter ++;
}

//  After 25 seconds stop timer and continue
loadtimer.Stop();

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loadtimercounter += 5;
}
```

I am searching for half a day... I tried to use Thread.sleep, timer, stopwatch, ... all in main thread or side thread..

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `Timer` and `Thread.Sleep` (`StopWatch` huh?) will not work for as long as you perform *long running job* in UI thread itself. You can try to *split* job and put *small parts* of job into timer (`switch/case` steps). Or you can use `Task`, `Thread` and `BackgroundWorker` to simple do that long work **not** in UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the work on a separate thread. Look into [asynchronous programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

Or you could just simply use multi threading. I would recommend using asynchronous programming for both doing the background work and updating the GUI's textbox control.

Comment: Yeah I am trying right now.. But the problem is my main thread continues.. And it need to pause 25 seconds and then move on. Cause after the 25 seconds I check if that bit is still high.

Comment: So you need to pause the main thread without blocking the GUI? Is that what you need?

Comment: Yeah... I am now doing a loop in the main thread to check if myThread.IsAlive is true or not.. If it is false then I can continue.. But now a new problem. I get an exception saying that there are object that are owned by another thread (I think the Textboxes)... :/ Can I use some sort of messagebox without an 'ok' button just to visualize that the program is busy?

Comment: I think it would be more helpful to show more code than just this part.

Comment: I can't put all my code here.. :( Do you know a way to pause the main thread for 25 seconds with an interval of 5 seconds while UI can be blocked but I need to show a box with waiting per 5 seconds?

Comment: @Ben I know how to sleep without blocking the GUI. In any async function use `await Task.Delay(milliseconds);`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a **background worker**.
There is a dedicated report progress event that can be used to update the loading box that you need.

[Background Worker Class and example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: But it seems so overkill to just visualize a little box with waiting for 25 seconds while checking some stuff in a loop..

Comment: That is the way to go, if you want to update the UI when you do something else there is no other way.  And this is not so bad, try it you will see, once you understand its very easy.